# File issues after importing Drupal site

Tags: 7, migrations, files

I recently tried to move my Drupal site to a new server using this page: [Moving Drupal 7 site to a new server](http://www.torylawson.com/index.php?title=Moving_Drupal_7_site_to_a_new_server).

But now the style doesn't seem be loaded and more importantly I get this error on every page in the site (even on the frontpage):

> Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://filef76T9k): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/drupal/includes/file.inc).
>
> The file could not be created.

Any ideas what this could be about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your temp directory is either wrong, or isn't writable.

Visit "admin/reports/status" and fix any problems that are there.

Then visit "admin/config/media/file-system" and make sure the temp directory is set properly and is writable by the webserver.

Comment: If you're unsure what the temp directory should be set to, you can just delete what is in there and click `Save configuration` and Drupal is usually pretty good at picking up the right one.

Comment: is there a way that i can do that though the terminal because apparently i cant login yet am also facing the same error

Comment: @solomonkitumba You can try it as `drush st`, but I am not sure if that will help in your case.

Comment: you can create a tmp file inside your /sites/default/files/ then should specify it in the media/file-system ->

Answer (score 0):

The error happens, because your temporary directory is not writable by your web server user.

You may check that in admin panel by going to *Reports* and *Status report* at: `/admin/reports/status`.

To fix it, you've to got to *File system* in *Configuration*, then change your *temporary directory* to point to your writable directory. If that's correct, then make you set the right permission on it, e.g.

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp
```

and the same for default files folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 sites/default/files
```

If you're using `drush`, check which folder is set currently by:

```
drush vget file_temporary_path
```

Then to fix it, try:

```
drush vset file_temporary_path /tmp
```